# How to display page's content after controller variables are initialized

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I'm new to angularJS and web in general so I'm interested if it's possible to display page after it's controller's $scope variables are initialized?
The thing is most of my $scope variables are used to manage dynamic look of a page. It comes to page is loading right on my eyes, and I realize things loading are my $scope things.
Is it possible to let controller load and calculate everything before it displays it on the screen?

Comment: read about [ng-cloak](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jun/02/AngularJs-ngcloak-Problems-on-large-Pages) or [here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/advent2013/#!/day/21)

Answer (score 0):

Not really... because part of Angular's philosophy is to do everything possible from the DOM, and the browser is going to see some of those before *any* Javascript gets executed at all.

However, Angular DOES have a standard trick to work around this. Please review the documentation for ngCloak:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak